# Converting a vector of strings into a numerical vector, based on string-sequences

Tags: r

I have a vector like

```
A <- c("A","A","B","B", "C","C","C", "D")
```

i would like to convert it into a numerical vector  based on the sequence in A, that would look like:

```
c(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your expected answer.  The length of "A" and "B" are different

Comment: The Vector B is my answer. I have A and want to turn it into B

Comment: But, A has 8 elements and B with 9

Comment: vector B is not "based on the sequence"

Comment: is `split(seq(A), A)` what you're looking for ?

Comment: I am sorry, this wasnt my intention.

Comment: @nouse: when you write something like `5:7`, what we read is actually `5 6 7`, and I think this is what causes the confusion here. We read your vector `c(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8)` as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, and `akrun`'s answer was spot on for that. He should not have been voted down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
A <- c("A","A","B","B", "C","C","C", "D")
as.numeric(factor(A))
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

and in case you really want a sequence from 1 to the `length` of the vector:

```
labels(factor(A))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8"
```

or

```
1:length(A)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If the first sequence is what you want, you may find `plyr::mapvalues` interesting in case you have more complicated cases at some point. For instance,

```
library(plyr)
mapvalues(A, from=unique(A), to=1:4)
[1] "1" "1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3" "4"
```

This comes in handy when you need a bit more control. For instance, you could easily supply other output as `to` argument, e.g.`month.name[1:4]`.

Comment: This is very close already. My package expects a vector to colorize a graph depending on factor level: I need to tell it where new factor levels begin (hence the 1:2,3:4,5:7,8 syntax). I see if it can work with these suggestions.

Comment: Just a note: If you need an indicator for the beginning of new factor level, assuming that your dataset is ordered along the factor level, you could try something like `diff(as.numeric(factor(A)))`. Most packages should be able to understand normal factors though.